# How to disallow special characters in PAN number using BackboneJS

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to add a PAN number validation to disallow special chars, but my code as follows is not working as expected:

```
if (attributes.isOwnProfile &&
    attributes.totalExperience > 0 &&
    $.trim(attributes.panNumber) == "") {
    errors.push({
        key: "panNo",
        message: "Required"
    });
} else if ($.trim(attributes.panNumber) != "" &&
    attributes.panNumber.length !== 10) {
    errors.push({
        key: "panNo",
        message: "Not a valid PAN No"
    });
} else if (!(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/).test(attributes.panNumber)) {
    errors.push({
        key: "panNo",
        message: "Not a valid PAN No"
    });
}
```

Comment: no Error .. its accepting pl character also. Regx /[^a-zA-Z0-9]/ is not working.

Comment: is this code part of model? is it getting executed ? paste the complete code

Comment: Yes, it's part of model, length validation  is working fine only regx part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is checking whether any special character is present or not, if present it returns true, which you're negating with the `!` operator, so the condition is not met when special characters are present.

You should remove the `!` from the if condition

```
else if((/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/).test(attributes.panNumber)) {
   errors.push({
      key: "panNo",
      message: "Not a valid PAN No"
      });
}
```